# Prove statement about a sequence of homeomorphisms $f_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

The problem statement:

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of homeomorphisms from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and let $F$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ that doesn't contain any rational number. Prove that there is a real number $r$ such that $r \not \in f_n(F)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

My attempt at a solution:

I am not so sure how to attack this problem, I suppose that it may be easier to prove it by the absurd or by the contrapositive.

So, suppose that for all $r \in \mathbb R$, $r \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} f_n(F)$.This means $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} f_n(F)$ Now, I would like to construct a sequence of real numbers $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $y_n \to z$ where $f^{-1}_n(y_n) \in F$ and $f^{-1}_{n_0}(z)=q$, for some natural number $n_0$ with $q \in \mathbb Q$.

I don't know how to continue, I would like to conclude that $q$ is a limit point of $F$ constructing an appropiate sequence in the image of each $f_n$ and arrive to the desired absurd $q \in F$.

Could anyone suggest me how to continue from here?

Comment: Note that even if the hypothesis were false, you wouldn't necessarily have $f_n(F)=\mathbb{R}$ for some particular $n$.  All you really can assume (for the proof by contrapositive) is that $\cup_n f_n(F)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right (sometimes I have problems with basic logic), I'll correct it.

Comment: This looks like an application of Baires Category Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem

Comment: Oh, I should prove that each $f_n(F)$ is nowhere dense and from there arrive to an absurd, right?

Comment: Yes and no :) You can proof that $f_{n}(F)$ is nowhere dense and then use Baire's Category Theorem, but actually in a direct way (no contradiction). At least this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Summary of comments:

1. Each $f_n(F)$ is closed, because $F$ is.
2. Each $f_n(F)$ has empty interior, because $F$ does.
3. Each $f_n(F)$ is nowhere dense, by 1 and 2  above.
4. By the Baire category, the union of $f_n(F)$ cannot be all of $\mathbb R$.